# Why did Subhas Chandra Bose lay the foundation of the Forward Bloc within the Indian National Congress, and not outside it?

Tags: india

We all know that Subhas Chandra Bose, after resigning from the Congress in April 29, 1939, laid the foundation of the Forward Bloc to unite all left wing members. But why did he do it under the Congress, and not on his own ?

Comment: I'm curious if this sentence in the ["History" section of the Forward Bloc wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_India_Forward_Bloc#Formation_of_the_Forward_Bloc) page doesn't answer the question: "Initially the aim of the Forward Bloc was to rally all the leftwing sections within the Congress and develop an alternative leadership inside the Congress."

Comment: Bad practice to begin a question with "We all know" - if it is that easy to document, please document.  Preliminary [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: My first frame challenge would be - why not? Is there an obvious better way that your research showed?